# Complex Join of two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

**edit:** The join that I want:

[image]

This is my current MySQL tables

table 'primary'

```
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
| id       | sample | mineral | formula   | link     |
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
| 1        | 5742   | calcite | CaCO3     | link..   |
| 2        | 3411   | siderite| Fe^2+^CO3 | link..   |
| .        | ....   | ........| ......... | ......   |
+----------+--------+---------+-----------+----------+
```

and table 'secondary'

```
+----------+------------+---------+-----------+
| id       | wavenumber | calcite | siderite  |
+----------+------------+---------+-----------+
| 1        | 1          | 256     | 434       |
| 2        | 3          | 254     | 312       |
| 3        | 5          | 251     | 424       |
| 4        | 7          | 257     | 544       |
| 5        | 9          | 258     | 345       |
| 6        | 11         | 257     | 386       |
| 7        | 13         | 326     | 314       |
| 8        | 15         | 456     | 337       |
| 9        | 17         | 236     | 243       |
| 10       | 19         | 246     | 514       |
| 11       | 21         | 254     | 662       |
| 12       | 23         | 258     | 248       |
| 13       | 25         | 230     | 374       |
| 14       | 27         | 224     | 359       |
| 15       | 29         | 216     | 442       |
| 16       | 31         | 236     | 344       |
| 17       | 33         | 247     | 343       |
| ..       | ..         | ...     | ...       |
+----------+------------+---------+-----------+
```

It is possible to combine in one query:
- a select all from row click of primary table with select all from weavenumber + specific column from secondary table:

**e.g.** if is clicked on row 2 of primary table, select all and also I want to select all from weavenumber and column 'siderite'.

Weavenumber column it is common for all selections, the only difference is column 3, 4, 5, and so on, which corresponds to the id of primary table.
It's possible to make a join like this?

I want to make a xy plot for every entry primary table, and in the secondary table, the weavenumber is the x-axe (horizontal) and calcite, siderite, etc. is the variable y-axe (vertical).

For now I have this:

```
private void primaryMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {  

int row = primary.getSelectedRow();
int realIndex = primary.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
String Table_click = (primary.getModel().getValueAt(realIndex, 0).toString());

    try {
            String sql = "select * from primary where id='" + Table_click + "' ";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {


                String add1 = rs.getString("mineral");
                txt_mineral.setText(add1);
                String add2 = rs.getString("formula");
                txt_formula.setText(add2);
                String add3 = rs.getString("link");
                txt_link.setText(add3);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

}
```

Comment: How do these tables relate to each other?  It doesn't seem clear.

Comment: column number? e.g. (n+1) I think I need a variable like row selection of first table.

Comment: Please consider my update at the beginning of the post.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for complete schema. Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39630)

Comment: The result set you are describing seems malformed. The part I am talking about is `all from wavenumber`. Do you want to add a field that contains all wavenumber values concatenated?

Comment: What I want is that for a specific row of table_A to join a select all from column 'weavenumber' (of table_B) + select all from column 'calcite'(table_B) (which is related to row selection of table_A).
If you see the update, with the blue color (weavenumber from table_B) is the same for all join selections

Comment: @ApopeiAndreiIonut is what I posted the same as what you required?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query I came up with:

```
SELECT     Prime.*, wavenumber, 
           CASE 
             WHEN Prime.mineral = 'calcite' 
             THEN calcite 
             ELSE siderite 
           END AS mineralval 
FROM       Second 
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Prime) AS Prime ON 1 = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee3cf/8